# How to trim whitespace from the end of a variable

Tags: string, emacs

I'm looking for an example, please, of how to delete one or more spaces from the end of a variable.

```
(let ((test-variable "hello "))

  (if (eq ?\s (aref test-variable (1- (length test-variable))))

    (setq test-variable "hello")))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple: `(car (split-string "hello       "))` ==> "hello"

You can also explicitly use argument `TRIM`, as the doc string recommends:

```
(split-string "hello   "
              split-string-default-separators
              t
              split-string-default-separators)
```

Comment: That works perfectly -- thank you very much.  :)  I was unaware that `split-string` comes with a trim option -- this will come in very handy in a variety of situations.

Comment: FAILs in general:`(car (split-string "Only want spaces at and deleted       "))
==> "Only"`

Answer (score 14):

In Emacs 24.4 (which is to be released later this year) this will be even simpler:

```
(require 'subr-x)

(string-trim-right "some string  ")
```

While you're waiting for 24.4 to come you can simply define `string-trim-right` locally:

```
(defun string-trim-right (string)
  "Remove trailing whitespace from STRING."
  (if (string-match "[ \t\n\r]+\\'" string)
      (replace-match "" t t string)
    string))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the helpful solution and also for a glimpse into the future of what is coming in version 24.4 -- greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

Or

```
(replace-regexp-in-string "\s+$" "" "bar    ")
"bar"
```

Comment: Thank you for the alternative solution -- much appreciated.

Comment: `$` signifies end of line, not end of string. You should use `\\'` instead.

Answer (score 1):

In a more general case, you might take the approach:

```
;; Create an utility function for this purpose
(defun strip-trailing-space (string)
   ;; We may use this twice, and `length' is an expensive operation
   (let ((last (1- (length string))))
      ;; is the last position a space?
      (if (eq ?\s (aref string last))
          ;; if so, return up to the position before it
          (subseq string 0 last)
          ;; if not, return the original string
          string)))
```

A more general function might accept a predicate to strip multiple characters or characters of a type, e.g.

```
(defun eq-space-p (char) (eq ?\s char))
(defun space-or-underline-p (char) (member char '(?\s ?_)))
(defun strip-trailing-chars (string &optional test)
  (let ((last (1- (length string))))
    (if (funcall (or test #'eq-space-p) (aref string last))
        (subseq string 0 last)
        string)))
```

Test:

```
(strip-trailing-space "hello ")   → "hello"
(strip-trailing-space "hello_")   → "hello_"

(strip-trailing-chars "hello ")   → "hello"
(strip-trailing-chars "hello_")   → "hello_"
(strip-trailing-chars "hello_"
                      #'space-or-underline-p) → "hello"
```

Using destructively:

```
(setq test-variable (strip-trailing-space test-variable))
```

(NB the destructive mutation of a variable is often a “code smell,” but there are certainly valid reasons in Emacs to do so.)

Comment: Thank you for the alternative solutions -- much appreciated.